# Binding a list of IPv4 addresses to Ubuntu Server quickly

Tags: server, ip, bind

Is there a bash script or tool to automatically bind a list of IPv4 addresses to an Ubuntu server quickly?

For example, let's say I have a text file named /root/iplist.txt
and in iplist.txt, I have one IP per line:

1.1.1.1

1.1.1.2

1.1.1.3

... and so on, until .30 let's say. How do I automatically bind that list of individual IPv4 addresses to the Ubuntu server?

I am aware of the ip command to bind a CIDR block (ip addr add 1.1.1.1/24 for example) however I am not sure how to quickly bind a range of individual IPs.

I know how to do this in [CentOS with ifcfg-eth1-range0](http://www.ducea.com/2006/07/15/linux-tips-how-to-quickly-bind-a-range-of-ips-on-redhat-based-systems/) but it doesn't appear this feature is available in Ubuntu...

I am sure this topic will come in handy for a lot of other people as I was only able to find tutorials on how to do this with CentOS despite my hours of researching I was not able to find anything for Ubuntu. So I am adding the appropriate tags to this post

Thanks for any help,

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, in case anyone was needing this! I searched for hours and couldn't find anything so decided to come up with something on my own! I really hope this helps others who were seeking the same solution.

for i in {1..128}; do echo iface eth1:$i inet static >> /etc/network/interfaces; echo address 192.168.0.$i >> /etc/network/interfaces; echo netmask 255.255.255.0 >> /etc/network/interfaces; echo auto eth1:$i >> /etc/network/interfaces; done

Replace 255.255.255.0 with your subnet, and replace 192.168.0. with the first 3 parts of your IP range
Edit "eth1" to eth0 or whatever your main network interface is.

And replace 1..128 accordingly, for example the above commnad would route .1 to .128.